# Selenium functions name shortenen in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

When i do import from `selenium.webdriver.support` it have long name as `expected_conditions`, this can be shortenen in this way `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`, but how to shorten functions names inside called `EC` ?

for example i need shorten function like `visibility_of_all_elements_located` to `VoAEL`

to call
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.VoAEL((By.XPATH, "//input[@role='combobox']")))`

instead of
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@role='combobox']")))`

as thoose functions name takes a lot of space in code.

So how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected conditions are classes, so you can use alias when importing them as well

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import visibility_of_all_elements_located as VoAEL

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(VoAEL((By.XPATH, "//input[@role='combobox']")))
```

I would suggest though to create a utility file with wait functions to reuse

util file:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


def voael(by, locator):
    return wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((by, locator)))


def poael(by, locator):
    return wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, locator)))

...
```

call:

```
voael(By.XPATH, "//input[@role='combobox']")
```